# How to output different arrays at the same index javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have a problem with my code:

**CODE:**

```
var row = ["1", "1"];
    var column = ["1", "2"];
    var song = ["36", "39"];

    var arrayLength = row.length;
    var arrayLength2 = column.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    for (var e = 0; e < arrayLength2; e++) {
    var samples = document.querySelectorAll('[data-row-id="'+row[i]+'"][data-column-id="'+column[e]+'"][data-parent-id="-1"]');

    for(var f = 0; f < samples.length; f++) {
        var sample = samples[f];

        sample.setAttribute('data-sample-id', song);
        console.log("Colore cambiato");
    }


    }
    }
```

This code basically have to do:

**How the code should act:**

```
<div class="cell" data-row-id="1" data-column-id="1" data-sample-id="36" data-parent-id="-1"></div>

<div class="cell" data-row-id="1" data-column-id="2" data-sample-id="39" data-parent-id="-1"></div>
```

**PROBLEM:**

But when i run it, in data-sample-id i have "36,39", in both of divs. 
I want have "36" when the data-row-id is "1" and the data-column-id is "1" and i want have "39" when the data-row-id is "1" and the data-column-id is "2"!

I don't know how resolve, please help me!

**UPDATE**

If i add the "i" index after song (song[i]) i have "39" in both the Divs. (http://prntscr.com/fq4wci)

**SOLVED!**

I used only `i` index for all arrays and works perfectly, thanks at all :)

**Code for users that have my problem:**

```
    var row = ["1", "1", "2","3"];
    var column = ["1", "2", "1","4"];
    var song = ["36", "39", "45", "22"];
var arrayLength = row.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
var samples = document.querySelectorAll('[data-row-id="'+row[i]+'"][data-column-id="'+column[i]+'"][data-parent-id="-1"]');
for(var f = 0; f < samples.length; f++) {
            var sample = samples[f];
            sample.setAttribute('data-sample-id', song[i]);
            console.log("Colore cambiato");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this : you need to use for-loop to set attribute for your desierd class.

```
var row = ["1", "1"];
    var column = ["1", "2"];
    var song = ["36", "39"];
var arrayLength = row.length;
var arrayLength2 = column.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
for (var e = 0; e < arrayLength2; e++) {
var samples = document.querySelectorAll('[data-row-id="'+row[i]+'"][data-column-id="'+column[e]+'"][data-parent-id="-1"]');


 }
        }

   for(var f = 0; f < samples.length; f++) {
   for(var s = 0; s < song.length; s++) {
            samples[f].setAttribute('data-sample-id', song[s]);
            console.log("Colore cambiato");
        }
        }
```

Comment: this give me "39" in both the divs

Comment: can you tell me ..whats your value of samples.length ?

Comment: console.log(samples.length); -> return 1

Comment: Read the other answer, i solved a problem but there is another one

Comment: implement for-loop which i did in my answer .... it will work if you add other values. let me know ... my answer is working or not ?

Comment: No, i have as "data-sample-id" only the last value of the "song" array... not in order

Comment: nothing bro.. see only the data-sample-id at the mid (the second), the first and the 3° are empty... x.x

Comment: SOLVED! I used only "i" index for all arrays and works perfectly, thanks at all :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the `index` of the array like `song[i]` in the inner loop.

```js
var row = ["1", "1"];
    var column = ["1", "2"];
    var song = ["36", "39"];


    var arrayLength = row.length;
    var arrayLength2 = column.length;

    var rows = 1;
    var columns = arrayLength2;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (var e = 0; e < columns; e++) {
    var samples = document.querySelectorAll('[data-row-id="'+row[i]+'"][data-column-id="'+column[e]+'"][data-parent-id="-1"]');

    for(var f = 0; f < samples.length; f++) {
        var sample = samples[f];
  
        sample.setAttribute('data-sample-id', song[e]);
        console.log(song[e]);
        console.log("Colore cambiato");
    }


    }
    }
```

```html
<div class="cell" data-row-id="1" data-column-id="1" data-parent-id="-1"></div>

<div class="cell" data-row-id="1" data-column-id="2" data-parent-id="-1"></div>
```

Comment: You have 4 div's, 2 would have 36 and 2 would have 39. Do you think otherwise ?

Comment: I have two div's! One with data-row-id = 1 and data-column-id = 1 and another div with data-row-id = 1 and data-column-id = 2
The first div would have "36" in "data-sample-id" and the other div would have "39" in "data-sample-id"

Comment: Then why are you looping for time, 2 for rows length and 2 for column length ?

Comment: is possible to do all in one loop?

Comment: Yeah works, but if i add other values, they are not displayed in order. For example if i do: var row = ["1", "1","2"]; var column = ["1", "2","1"]; var song = ["36", "39","45"];
I would want to display in row 1 and column 1 the song 36. in row 1 and column 2 the song 39. In row 2 and column 1 the song 45. 
With your method i see "45" in the first div... and the 3° values does not appear

Comment: I have already given you the reference. This website is not for asking others to write the code for you. Check the logic for the Rows and Columns and then display it accordingly. Not sure why you downvoted..

Comment: i can't vote, i have no 15 of reputation, another user downvoted you xD